# How do i get the root, not the document root

Tags: php

I want to upload images outside the document root:

```
// on server:
/home1/myname/artist_gallery

// on localhost
c:/artist_gallery
```

I use the following to create the `DEFINE` for both local and server:

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('GALLERY_FILE', DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/artist_gallery/');
```

but, i get

```
/home1/myname/public_html/artist_gallery
C:/public_html/artist_gallery
```

Notice the folder **public_html**... i dont want that folder...

So, how do I get the root (not the document root) in one `DEFINE` rule for both the localhost and server?

Comment: try dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) and see what happens

Comment: Try this: define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])); define('GALLERY_FILE', '../' . DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/artist_gallery/');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file structure like

```
/home1/myname/
  --- public_html/        # all site files
  --- artist_gallery/     # gallery dir
```

You need to define you constants like:

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
// will point to document_root, it is `/home1/myname/public_html/`

define('GALLERY_FILE', realpath(DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/../artist_gallery/'));
// path will be resolved and will point to `/home1/myname/artist_gallery/`
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get root by simply using a single `/` before the `artist_gallery` directory, like this:

```
define('GALLERY_FILE', '/artist_gallery/');
```

Comment: And uploading files to `ROOT` will put'em there? Into the root of a disk?

Comment: No, but it can write to `GALLERY_FILE`

Comment: Why define `ROOT` then?

Comment: @u_mulder Just thought it might be more clear to him like that.

Answer (score 0):

in localhost change valuse of DocumentRoot in your file php.ini -> DocumentRoot "C:/public_html/"
to DocumentRoot "C:/"
And if you are not the server's host, you will not be able to